# How to get CSV data line by line if all csv data comes in a sigle line?

Tags: php, csv

I need this ans :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Customer First Name
    [1] => Customer Last Name
    [2] => Date
    [3] => Is Anonymous
    [4] => Rating
    [5] => Title
    [6] => Review
    [7] => EMail

)

Array
(
    [0] => TODD
    [1] => JACKMAN
    [2] => 6/17/13
    [3] => FALSE
    [4] => 5
    [5] => Outstanding service as always!
    [6] => Outstanding service as always!
    [7] => abc@al.com

)

Array
(
    [0] => Gary
    [1] => Peters
    [2] => 6/19/13
    [3] => FALSE
    [4] => 5
    [5] => From my description Ari suggested...
    [6] => From my description Ari suggested what the problem might be. It was as he suspected. Got a replacement part at the best price. Installation was prompt and successful. Still one of the best places to go for auto repair.
    [7] => abc@test.com

)
```

But i am getting :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Customer First Name
    [1] => Customer Last Name
    [2] => Date
    [3] => Is Anonymous
    [4] => Rating
    [5] => Title
    [6] => Review
    [7] => EMail
TODD
    [8] => hjk
    [9] => JACKMAN
    [10] => 6/17/13
    [11] => FALSE
    [12] => 5
    [13] => Outstanding service as always!
    [14] => Outstanding service as always!
    [15] => abc@al.com
Kliop
    [16] => Gary
    [17] => Peters
    [18] => 6/19/13
    [19] => FALSE
    [20] => 5
    [21] => From my description Ari suggested...
    [22] => From my description Ari suggested what the problem might be. It was as he suspected. Got a replacement part at the best price. Installation was prompt and successful. Still one of the best places to go for auto repair.
    [23] => abc@test.com

)
```

Please help me...

Comment: If CSV data comes as a single line, then technically it's invalid csv data; but if you know how many columns you should have in each row (8 in your case), then use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) after reading it

Comment: my csv has multiple rows but at the time of importing in php its coming in single array not in multiple array row wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
$lines = file('test.csv');

    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
         $data = explode(',',$line);
         echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
    }
```

hope it's helpfull for you

Comment: How is it likely to be helpful? OP's problem is that his file has only one line

Comment: Hi its working for me as new line for my data, its exactly like what i want ... thanks.